# Иерархический запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: oracle, plsql

Имеются две таблицы: category(`id, par_id references category, name`) и goods(`id, cat_id references category, name`).

Нужно вывести деревом в таком виде:

```
Категория 
  Подкатегория
  Товар подкатегории
```

Запрос на вывод деревом из одной таблицы сделал:

```
SELECT 
  LPAD(' ', (level - 1) * 2) || name
FROM category
CONNECT BY PRIOR id=par_id
START WITH par_id IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY name;;
```

Результат:

```
name
----------------
Видеокарты
  ASUS
  Gainward
  MSI
Оперативная память
  Kingston
  Samsung
Процессоры
  AMD
  Intel
```

Пробовал выводить через union из двух таблиц, но не получается. Подскажите, как можно правильно вывести?

Вот что получилось когда пробовал:

```
SELECT 
  LPAD(' ', (level - 1) * 2) || name
FROM category
CONNECT BY PRIOR id=par_id
START WITH par_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT
  LPAD(' ', (level - 1) * 2) || g.name
FROM goods g, category c
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR g.cat_id=c.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

Без `NOCYCLE` выдает ошибку `ORA-01436: цикл CONNECT BY в данных пользователя`. Второй `LPAD` не пойму как настроить, чтобы отступы были как по шаблону.

Результат:

```
"Name"
"            AMD Phenom II x4 960T"
"            ASUS GeForce 410"
"            Gainward GeForce 560"
"            Intel i7-4770k"
"            Kingston 1800MHZ"
"            MSI GeForce GTX 750"
"            MSI GeForce GTX 750TI"
"            Samsung 1666MHZ"
"          AMD Phenom II x4 960T"
"          ASUS GeForce 410"
"          Gainward GeForce 560"
"          Intel i7-4770k"
"          Kingston 1800MHZ"
"          MSI GeForce GTX 750"
"          MSI GeForce GTX 750TI"
"          Samsung 1666MHZ"
"        AMD Phenom II x4 960T"
"        ASUS GeForce 410"
"        Gainward GeForce 560"
"        Intel i7-4770k"
"        Kingston 1800MHZ"
"        MSI GeForce GTX 750"
"        MSI GeForce GTX 750TI"
"        Samsung 1666MHZ"
"      AMD Phenom II x4 960T"
"      ASUS GeForce 410"
"      Gainward GeForce 560"
"      Intel i7-4770k"
"      Kingston 1800MHZ"
"      MSI GeForce GTX 750"
"      MSI GeForce GTX 750TI"
"      Samsung 1666MHZ"
"    AMD Phenom II x4 960T"
"    ASUS GeForce 410"
"    Gainward GeForce 560"
"    Intel i7-4770k"
"    Kingston 1800MHZ"
"    MSI GeForce GTX 750"
"    MSI GeForce GTX 750TI"
"    Samsung 1666MHZ"
"  AMD"
"  AMD Phenom II x4 960T"
"  ASUS"
"  ASUS GeForce 410"
"  Gainward"
"  Gainward GeForce 560"
"  Intel"
"  Intel i7-4770k"
"  Kingston"
"  Kingston 1800MHZ"
"  MSI"
"  MSI GeForce GTX 750"
"  MSI GeForce GTX 750TI"
"  Samsung"
"  Samsung 1666MHZ"
"AMD Phenom II x4 960T"
"ASUS GeForce 410"
"Gainward GeForce 560"
"Intel i7-4770k"
"Kingston 1800MHZ"
"MSI GeForce GTX 750"
"MSI GeForce GTX 750TI"
"Samsung 1666MHZ"
"Видеокарты"
"Оперативная память"
"Процессоры"
```

**UPD**: Добавил второй запрос.

**UPD2**: Добавил сортировку к первому запросу.

Comment: пробовали через union как ? потому что по моему представлению если этот запрос выполнить как раз из union вместо одной таблицы, при условии что в выборке из goods поле id будет NULL (на случай если оно пересекается значениями с категориями) и cat_id в качестве par_id, должно дать именно то, что требуется

Comment: @Mike, вопрос обновил, посмотрите второй запрос. Атрибут id у goods является первичный ключом, NULL там нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT LPAD(' ', (level - 1) * 2) || name
    FROM (
          select id,   par_id, name from category
          union all
          select NULL, cat_id, name from goods
         ) X
 CONNECT BY PRIOR id=par_id
   START WITH par_id IS NULL
   ORDER SIBLINGS BY name
```

Только если вы хотите что бы названия товаров не были сдвинуты относительно подкатегории, в которой находятся, надо вычесть из level еще 1 в случае если id is null

Comment: Так вот как оно соединяется через union. Спасибо, теперь корректно показывает.