# Как присоединить третью таблицу в иерархическом запросе из двух таблиц, чтобы использовать SUM()?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Имеются три таблицы: category(`c_id, par_id references category, name`), goods(`g_id, cat_id references category, name`), moves(`goods_id references goods, price`).

[Деревом получилось вывести](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746403/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/). Но теперь нужно присоединить третью таблицу `moves` и использовать `SUM()` по полю `moves.price`

Пробовал присоединить таблицу `moves` вот так:

```
SELECT 
  LPAD(' ', (level - 1) * 2) || t.name AS "Name"
FROM (
    select NULL, c_id, par_id, name from category
    union all
    select g_id, NULL, cat_id, name from goods
  ) t
LEFT JOIN moves m ON m.goods_id=t.g_id
CONNECT BY PRIOR t.cat_id=t.par_id
START WITH t.par_id IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY t.name;
```

Чтобы получилось соединить таблицы `goods` и `moves` по ключам, добавил g_id в union-запросе и когда попробовал присоединить по m.goods_id=t.g_id, то выдало ошибку `ORA-00904: "T"."G_ID": недопустимый идентификатор`.

**UPD**:

@Mike, написал подзапрос и склеил с деревом. Но теперь как в SELECT вывести `SUM(price)` из подзапроса?

```
LEFT JOIN 
 (
  SELECT
      SUM(price), goods_id
  FROM moves
  GROUP BY goods_id
 ) x
ON t.g_id=x.goods_id
```

**UPD2**: Нужно было просто добавить алиас (`SUM(price) AS sum_price`) и вызвать по нему в `SELECT` (`x.sum_price`).

Comment: в union имена полей всей выборки формируются по первому select. поэтому в первом запросе делайте `select NULL g_id, ... from catgory`

Comment: Поле g_id принадлежит таблице goods. Я не понимаю как исправить запрос по комментарию

Comment: `NULL g_id` означает что мы поле со значением NULL называем g_id, т.е. делаем для него алиас, для ясности конечно можете добавить слово AS, `NULL AS g_id` так что просто допишите в запросе после NULL пробел и алиас для поля

Comment: Получилось, спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: `SUM()` получилось использовать с `GROUP BY`, в итоге по товарам сумма появилась. А для уровня подкатегорий и категорий чтобы `SUM()` вывести, то нужно будет вложенные запросы в `SELECT` писать или как-то можно проще сделать?

P.S.: Также теперь из-за `GROUP BY` не работает `ORDER SIBLINGS BY t.name`. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Вы слишком много хотите и дерево и сгруппировать что то. Если нужны только суммы, то получайте сразу сгруппированные суммы и подклеивайте на дерево. (т.е. left join делайте не с таблицей, а с подзапросом, который получит нужные суммы с group by good_id). На счет суммирования вверх по дереву, пока не знаю, надо подумать

Comment: @Mike, я обновил вопрос. Посмотрите, правильно ли я сделал подзапрос и как вывести сгруппированные суммы? UPD: нужно было просто добавить алиас. С этим разобрался. Есть идеи как вывести суммы по иерархии?

Comment: Ну вы ему имя дайте `sum(price) as price` например и спокойно выводите x.price Разумеется это будет только на уровне товара. Распространение вверх по дереву пока не придумал ничего красивого, только подзапрос на каждом узле, который будет собирать сумму для всего поддерева (т.е. скорее всего то же будет с connect by)

Comment: Да, с алиасом уже разобрался. Можете пример показать как будет выглядеть с подзапросами по иерархии?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575185/hierarchical-query-and-counting-siblings

Comment: Большое спасибо за ссылку, буду разбираться. Не знаете где можно почитать про иерархии с такими сложными запросами и где хорошо разбираются такие нюансы?

Comment: А я пока думаю над чем то более красивым, мне эти подзапросы дико не нравятся :) хотя более красивое в итоге может оказаться более громоздким :)

Comment: Достаточно чтобы работало и выводило как нужно. Я и такому буду очень рад :)

Comment: Сделал пока подзапросом, но не по исходным таблицам, а по самому запросу, что должно быть быстрее ...

Comment: Правда у меня третьей таблицы нет, так что я предположил, что прайс лежит прямо в goods, но это не влияет на результат, свой запрос с left join внутрь CTE кладите и sys_connect_by_path дописывайте и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE as(
      SELECT LPAD(' ', (level - 1) * 2) || name name, price, rownum RN,
             sys_connect_by_path(name,'/') path
        FROM (
              select id,   par_id, name, NULL price from category
              union all
              select NULL, cat_id, name, num from goods
             ) X
     CONNECT BY PRIOR id=par_id
       START WITH par_id IS NULL
       ORDER SIBLINGS BY X.name
)
select name,
       coalesce(price, (select sum(price) from CTE B where B.path like A.path||'/%' )) price
  from CTE A order by RN
```

При условии, что не может быть одноименных категорий, которые дадут одинаковые пути. Если они есть, то в путь надо собирать что нибудь уникальное, например ID

Comment: Я думал будет много нагромождений, а оказывается все кратко. Спасибо, подставил свое и все заработало :)